# Building standalone Spring Boot app with hibernate connection

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to build a simple application, which connects with database and saves some data in it, let's say once per hour. I found some tutorials on pages like baeldung, but their solutions doesn't work for me.

Here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="io.github.steve"/>

        <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames" value="messages"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/articles?useSSL=false"/>
<property name="user" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value=""/>
<property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactoryXXX" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="io.github.steve.webscraping.domain"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryXXX"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>

        </beans>
```

ArticlesDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class ArticlesDaoImpl implements ArticlesDao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Article> query = session.createQuery("from Article order by uploadDate", Article.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(article);
    }



}
```

ArticlesServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class ArticlesServiceImpl implements ArticlesService {
    @Autowired
    private ArticlesDao articlesDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        return articlesDao.getAllArticles();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        articlesDao.addArticle(article);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        articles.stream().forEach(articlesDao::addArticle);
    }
}
```

And now: 
First of all, I don't know where should I put my xml config file.
I have no idea how to build my Main.class. I want to Autowire ArticlesService to Main class and run a method from it. When i use just SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args), it loads and finishing with exit code 1.

Main app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

ScheduledTasks:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
@Autowired
ArticlesService articlesService;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);


@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * *")
public void reportCurrentTime() {
    articlesService.addArticles(new MkyongWebScraper().getArticlesList());
}
```

}

I'm really new in Spring and I know this question is pretty wide, but I can't find any suitable sources for my tasks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are mixing a few concepts (e.g. Spring Boot is typically not used with XML-configuration). Have a look at the Spring Boot reference guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ and the samples provided by the Spring Boot Team (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples). These are up to date compared to the often outdated tutorials from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the code you are writing, especially the XML config does not take advantage of the easier and more convenient offered with Spring Boot, and Spring Boot 2.

To generate the skeleton of your project, go to [Spring Boot Initializer](https://start.spring.io/). You can choose the dependencies you want (in your case, it should "JPA" which is based on Spring Data JPA) and then you can download a zip with your project.

You might want to have a look at [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/). There are also some pretty interesting videos to "get started with Spring Boot" on youtube..

Once you have your project, you can add Spring Data JPA code... 
Spring Boot documentation has a section about [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data), but you can also find more info in the [documentation of Spring Data JPA project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa).

Best of luck

Comment: As You mentioned, I shouldn't configure Spring through XML. But if not by XML, where do I put database connection configuration? Through h2 web console?

Comment: The settings related to your data source and database connection can all be defined within your configuration file (application.properties or application.yml). You can see this in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql). There is also a good tutorial to get you started : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem. I just didn't understood Spring enough. For people like me I recommend Spring in Action by Craig Walls.